# I can not exacute a modify bash script

Tags: bash, unix, centos

I modify a bash script and i try to execute it and it did not work. The msg was

> sudo: unable to execute /opt/dcm4chee-2.17.3-mysql/bin/install_arr.sh:
>   No such file or directory

I check that `install_arr.sh` exists in the specific path and it has the execution permision.

Do you have any ideas what is the problem?:/

Comment: Are you sure `/opt/dcm4chee-2.17.3-mysql/bin/install_arr.sh` exists? check if the full path matches.

Comment: This can typically happen when user you are logged in with can access the file, but sudo user (if different of course) cant access it.

Comment: fedorqui I checked that and it's ok. Manish Sapariya, I logged as root user and before modify the file I can execute it

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referring to something *inside* the script that it can't find.  Probably in one of the line you added.

Comment: actually I change only a number of version:/